# PHP: function glob() on Windows - patterns with multiple ranges

Tags: php, windows, glob

I want a list of images in a directory ($path). I want to perform a case-insensitive research about file extension. This code below works well on Linux, but not on Windows.

```
foreach ( glob("$path/{*.[jJ][pP][gG],*.[jJ][pP][eE][gG],*.[gG][iI][fF],*.[pP][nN][gG],*.[bB][mM][pP],*.[tT][iI][fF][fF]}", GLOB_BRACE | GLOB_NOCHECK ) as $file ) {

   echo $file;

}
```

I added GLOB_NOCHECK flag to view the computed patterns. Here's the response:

```
fotogallery/dir/[gG]
fotogallery/dir/[gG]
fotogallery/dir/[fF]
fotogallery/dir/[gG]
fotogallery/dir/[pP]
fotogallery/dir/[fF]
```

It seems that only last range ([...]) of each comma-separated expression is considered!
Why this happens?

Thank you! :-)

Comment: Why would you even keep the ranges. Windows is case insensitive, so you can just use *.jpg, *.jpeg etc..

Comment: @DamienOvereem According to the PHP Manual glob is case sensitive, even on Windows systems.

Comment: @DamienOvereem I tried as you suggested, it works! :-) thank you so much!! How can I vote your comment?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, it's true! The official documentation is inexact... strange!!

Comment: Added it as answer so you can close your question. Just hit the checkbox left of the answer. And you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

This may help you fix your problem

[PHP Manual comment about this sort of issue](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#56231)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on windows platform, you can simply remove the ranges. Just use *.jpeg,*.jpg etc.